# Rename files in folder, ignoring current file name

Tags: c#, version-control, fileinfo

I am trying to make myself a small version control service.

I want to have a program that monitors a folder, and when a new file is added it will rename that new file.

I have got the above functionality working, however i need to specify a file name for the fucntion to work.

I want it to rename the file regardless of what it is currently called.

for instance, i drag a file in called: "this is the final copy.png" and it will rename it to v1.png, the next file is called, "finalfinaltheend.png" and it will be renamed v2.png.

This is what i have so far:

Currently when i drag a new file in the folder it will search all the files and look for a string i have specified and change it. I want it to rename the files sequentially regardless of what the file name is when it is moved into the folder.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        watch();
    }

    private void watch()
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\jmorrish\Desktop\New folder\New folder";
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = path;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jmorrish\Desktop\New folder\New folder");
        FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
        {
            File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.Replace("I have been renamed", "123"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the behavior that is happening that isn't desired (or if nothing happens at all).

Comment: @CDove I did have that in the orignal question, but i have made it more obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enumerating every file each time your OnChanged method is called, but you should use the (FileSystemEventArgs e) instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

FileSystemEventArgs provides ChangeType, FullPath and Name properties that will help you get the modified file information. So instead of iterating over the entire folder, you just rename the file being modified.

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    File.Move(e.FullPath, e.FullPath.Replace(e.Name, $"123{Path.GetExtension(e.Name)}"));
}
```

You should take a look at Path class too, there you will find many common operations to work with paths, filenames, extensions, etc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This works, however, when it renames the files it loses its file extention.

Comment: Take a look at the Path class. I updated the answer to add a call to Path.GetExtension so you don't lose the extension.